# How can I handle error from batchAll extrinsic

Tags: polkadot-js, pallet

Example:

```js
// construct a list of transactions we want to batch
const txs = [
  api.tx.balances.transfer(addrBob, 12345), (1)
  api.tx.balances.transfer(addrEve, 12345), (2)
  api.tx.staking.unbond(12345) (3)
];

// construct the batch and send the transactions
api.tx.utility
  .batch(txs)
  .signAndSend(sender, ({ status }) => {
    if (status.isInBlock) {
      console.log(included in ${status.asInBlock});
    }
});
```

If transaction (2) failed ( don't have enough balance fee to send anymore). So how can I block all the chain transactions or if don't, how can I handle the error comes out?

Currently, The batchAll method does not respond to any error and the result is, (1), (3) success, and 2 fail.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Iker mentioned `batch_all` sends a batch of dispatch calls and **atomically** executes them. The whole transaction will **rollback** and **fail** if any of the calls fail.

This video on the utility pallet may be helpful:

- https://youtu.be/WzuMCxwOzJM?t=1883

Here is an example for listening for `system.ExtrinsicFailed` as noted [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx#how-do-i-get-the-decoded-enum-for-an-extrinsicfailed-event):

```js
const txs = [
  api.tx.balances.transfer(EVE, 5000000),
  // api.tx.balances.setBalance(EVE, 100000000, 0),
  api.tx.identity.clearIdentity(),
  api.tx.system.remark('hello world'.repeat(10)),
]

await api.tx.utility.batchAll(txs).signAndSend(alice, ({ status, events }) => {
  if (status.isInBlock || status.isFinalized) {
    events
      // find/filter for failed events
      .filter(({ event }) =>
        api.events.system.ExtrinsicFailed.is(event)
      )
      // we know that data for system.ExtrinsicFailed is
      // (DispatchError, DispatchInfo)
      .forEach(({ event: { data: [error, info] } }) => {
        if (error.isModule) {
          // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
          const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(error.asModule);
          const { docs, method, section } = decoded;

          console.log(`${section}.${method}: ${docs.join(' ')}`);
        } else {
          // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
          console.log(error.toString());
        }
      });
  }
});
```

Output:

```
identity.NotNamed: Account isn't named.
```

If you are using **sudo** then you would listen for the `Sudid` event as noted [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx#how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-sudo-event):

```js
const txs = [
  api.tx.balances.forceTransfer(ALICE, BOB, 100),
  // api.tx.balances.transfer(EVE, 5000000),
  api.tx.balances.setBalance(BOB, 1000, 0),
  api.tx.balances.forceTransfer(BOB, EVE, 10000),
  api.tx.system.remark('hello world'.repeat(10)),
]

const unsub = await api.tx.sudo.sudo(api.tx.utility.batchAll(txs)).signAndSend(alice, ({ status, events }) => {
  if (status.isInBlock || status.isFinalized) {
    events
      // We know this tx should result in `Sudid` event.
      .filter(({ event }) =>
        api.events.sudo.Sudid.is(event)
      )
      // We know that `Sudid` returns just a `Result`
      .forEach(({ event : { data: [result] } }) => {
        // Now we look to see if the extrinsic was actually successful or not...
        if (result.isError) {
          let error = result.asError;
          if (error.isModule) {
            // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
            const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(error.asModule);
            const { docs, name, section } = decoded;

            console.log(`${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`);
          } else {
            // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
            console.log(error.toString());
          }
        }
      });
    unsub();
  }
});
```

Output:

```
balances.InsufficientBalance: Balance too low to send value
```

Comment: this is done batchAll in the interface. I want to handle errors in code. any example?

Comment: The video shows an example where there is an error in the `batch_all`, specifically [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzuMCxwOzJM&t=1883s). You will get a `system.ExtrinsicFailed` event with the error of the specific transaction that failed.

Comment: understood that error showing. But I want to ask to handle the error at codes.

Comment: Updated with a code example.

Comment: In your case. Is the method throwing an error and stopping transactions? 
I do exactly your example but in console.log error on chrome. I don't see any throwing error message

Comment: If one transaction throws an error, `batch_all` will rollback all transactions and my code shows the error of the transaction it failed on. I am running this on nodeJs and the error shows in the terminal.

Comment: if it does not throw an error, is it a problem with the provider when creating an API instance?

Comment: It is hard to say without more info to reproduce your issue. I would say, study the `batch_all` code and how PolkadotJs works with events and that should help you. If you have a reproducible problem then I suggest you create a new question on StackExchange where we can debug this with clear and concise details on how to reproduce it

Answer (score 1):

If you need atomic execution of all the batched calls in the transaction you have to use the `batch_all` method. With this call, the whole transaction will rollback and fail if any of the calls failed.

You can check [the source code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/3b0f4b205e72076357d2b555dbb745ceb8807672/frame/utility/src/lib.rs#L291) of this dispatchable for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I found this example. it helps me to log the error, Transactions are still executed and a few seconds later the console.log is displayed. I tried putting in try-catch but it doesn't jump in catch()

```
api.tx.balances
  .transfer(recipient, 123)
  .signAndSend(sender, ({ status, events, dispatchError }) => {
    // status would still be set, but in the case of error we can shortcut
    // to just check it (so an error would indicate InBlock or Finalized)
    if (dispatchError) {
      if (dispatchError.isModule) {
        // for module errors, we have the section indexed, lookup
        const decoded = api.registry.findMetaError(dispatchError.asModule);
        const { docs, name, section } = decoded;

        console.log(`${section}.${name}: ${docs.join(' ')}`);
      } else {
        // Other, CannotLookup, BadOrigin, no extra info
        console.log(dispatchError.toString());
      }
    }
  });
```